# If a plant / herb (grown in Eretz Yisrael) is used for its essence / aroma, must one first separate Terumah and Maaser (tithes) from it?

Tags: halacha, maaser-tithes, agriculture, smell

If a plant / herb (grown in Eretz Yisrael) is used for its essence / aroma, must one first separate *Terumah* and *Maaser* (tithes) from it?

Does it make a difference if it is atype of plant which is usually used for smelling rather than eating?

Does it make a difference whether it was planted specifically for the use of smelling?

Answer (score 2):

One separates terumah and maaser from food ([Mishna Maaser 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Maasrot.1.1?lang=bi), [MT Terumot 2:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/992028/jewish/Terumot-Chapter-2.htm)). As such an herb which is used for essence/aroma/smell but can also be used for food (e.g., mint/nana) requires terumah and maaser (see e.g., [here](http://dinonline.org/2017/10/17/trumos-maasros-potted-mint/) from dinonline).

I don't see one can take terumah and maaser from a plant used only for smelling (e.g., rhododendron, dogwood, wisteria and holly as suggested by @DanF) - after all terumot and maasrot were meant to be eaten (by Kohanim, Leviim, the poor, etc.) so one cannot give them something that can't be eaten.

Comment: They probably all can be eaten. The question is about how much designation as food do they need. Rov users in the location? Intent of the farmer? The buyer?